# Версия приложения для планшета

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно адаптировать мой проект под планшет. Казалось бы, ничего сложного - нужно просто задать нужную разметку в зависимости от того, планшет использует пользователь или телефон. Но как определить, какое устройство используется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте реализовать таким способом:
[Supporting different screens.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-layouts)

Answer (score 1):

Если размер экрана большой, задаем другой layout. Чтобы определить, какой используется сейчас, измените id и ищите так:

```
isTablet = findViewById(R.id.big) != null;
```